# Trouble understanding this behaviour of Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get through some Javascript problems when this one caught me off guard. Have a look at the following snippet,

```
var person = [];
person['1'] = "John";
person['2'] = "Doe";
person['3'] = 46; 
//[1: "John", 2: "Doe", 3: 46]
console.log(person);
//4 <-- as i expected
console.log(person.length);

var person2 = [];
person2['a'] = "John";
person2['b'] = "Doe";
person2['c'] = 46; 
//[1: "John", 2: "Doe", 3: 46]
console.log(person2);
//0 <-- i expected 4, but got 0
console.log(person2.length)
```

I have added the output in comments.

I am trying to figure out why

```
console.log(person2.length)
```

gives length 0 instead of 4. Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: You're treating `person2` as an object, not an array.  Objects don't have a length.

Comment: [Not a dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable), but the accepted answer might explain a lot.

Comment: The length of an array is always the highest numeric key + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is this:
In JavaScript, arrays are accessed by their *index* (e.g. 0,1,2,3. ..). What you're doing is assigning a *key* and a *value* to `person2`. Instead of this, just use

```js
var person2 = [];
person2[0] = "John";
person2[1] = "Doe";
person2[2] = 46;
```

Alternatively, you can access the length of the Object you created like this:

```js
var person2 = [];
person2['a'] = "John";
person2['b'] = "Doe";
person2['c'] = 46; 
console.log(person2); //[1: "John", 2: "Doe", 3: 46]
console.log(Object.keys(person2).length)
```

This works because although you defined it as an array, JavaScript arrays are already Objects anyway, so you can use `Object.keys(name).length` to access the length.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript **[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)** doesn't have `key:value` but just the value, your code may should looks like :

```js
var person = [];
person[0] = "John";
person[1] = "Doe";
person[2] = 46;
console.log(person);
console.log(person.length);
```

Or also using `push` :

```js
var person = [];
person.push("John");
person.push("Doe");
person.push(46); 
console.log(person);
console.log(person.length);
```

If you want your data to be stored by `key/value` you could use `object` :

```js
var person = {};
person['1'] = "John";
person['2'] = "Doe";
person['3'] = 46; 
console.log(person);
console.log(Object.keys(person).length);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @connexo Any string can be used as a property name, you just have to use bracket notation for ones that wouldn't work with dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only knows **index-based arrays**, starting at 0. You access array elements like `arr[n]` where `n` is an **integer** with `n >=0` and `n < arr.length`. You have tried to use strings instead of integers.

Furthermore, since arrays are objects in Javascript, you can also add properties to that object which you did by using `person['1'] = "John";`. Since arrays are also objects in Javascript, this creates the property named `1` on the person object.

On objects, you can access (or create) properties in two ways:

```
var obj = {};
// variant one using dot-notation
obj.prop = "whatever";
// identical result, different syntax:
obj["prop"] = "whatever";
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Javascript are objects-- as such, when you are doing:

```
person2['a'] = "John";
person2['b'] = "Doe";
person2['c'] = 46;
```

You're setting properties of the `person2` object.  If you want a cleaner way to add items to an array I recommend looking at [`array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 0):

For first one you will get 4 because its index-based array.

so JavaScript will count 4 its position of pointer on stack

and for the second one its associative array. so there is no matter of index at all.we can access it only based on key or using for-each.

in 2nd you will get length 3 given below.

```
var person = [];
person.push("John");
person.push("Doe");
person.push(46); 
console.log(person);
console.log(person.length);
```